# getting an error on a list of lists :TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to call the function tfidf on a list of lists total_all. I am getting an error message on running the line below: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

```
tfidf(total_all)

def tfidf(documents):
   global dftfidf
   dftfidf = pd.DataFrame() 
   tokenized_documents = [tokenize(d) for d in documents]
   idf = inverse_document_frequencies(tokenized_documents)
   for term in idf.keys():
       tf = sublinear_term_frequency(term, document)
       doc_tfidf.append(tf * idf[term])
       tfidf_documents.append(doc_tfidf)
       dftfidf=pd.DataFrame(data ={'term frequency':tf,'tfidf':doc_tfidf}) 
   return dftfidf

tfidf(total_all)
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including a full traceback of the error message and a toy dataset that reproduces the error.

Comment: And perhaps you are getting that error for your `for` loop, right? Please check first what `idf` returns. Pay also attention to first line, call function after is being defined.